Procedure for data import from file_name parameter
I want to automate table creation and import for a large number of csv files into my database.  I simply want to use a text parameter to build the file path inside the procedure.
The copy statement works fine if I don't use a variable as part of the file name, but I get an error in the FROM clause.
Please help if you can.  Thanks.


Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.

If you look at the COPY command syntax in the manual, you'll see that it won't accept variables for the file name, only literal strings:
COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
    FROM { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDIN }

You need to construct and execute your COPY command dynamically:
...
EXECUTE format('COPY version_name (reference, text) FROM ''%s''...', fpath);
...


That worked!  I actually did some more research and was trying the format construct.  Problem was I used double quotes "" instead of two single quotes.  But my code works now.  Thanks alot.

format(......,  quote_literal(fpath)) might be wise, to prevent injection/correctness issues when ' apostrophes are embedded in the file name.
